# Phaser-How to make a infinite ground?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm a noob in Phaser, I'm working on Flappy Bird. I try to make an infinite ground, I've tried tilePosition, but it's not working.

```
var ground;
function preload(){
  game.load.image('ground', '/assets/groud.png');
}
function create(){
  ground = game.add.tileSprite(0, 480, 'ground');
}
function update(){
  ground.tilePosition.x -= 1;
}
```

But it's not working.Can anybody help me?

Comment: In general with computer related stuff, just saying "it's not working" is not enough. Do you get an error message? Is it displaying a blank screen? Is the sprite not moving?

Comment: Consider commenting or accepting answers in future, so maybe someone will help you.

Comment: Did you notice you have a type in your path of your image? groud.png instead of ground.png?

Answer (score 1):

The [constructor for TileSprite](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.TileSprite.html) requires the parameters `x, y, width, height, key` (and `frame`, but that only applies to spritesheets not when using `image`).

So I think you forgot the width and height parameters, causing Phaser to see the 'ground' as the width. This probably raises an error message on the JavaScript console. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in Chrome or <kbd>F12</kbd> in FireFox, and check the console for any messages.

Also, I don't know what resolution you are using but the parameter `480` is the y position and maybe this causes the TileSprite to be located below the screen so it's not visible?

Maybe try this instead:

```
function create(){
    ground = game.add.tileSprite(0, 100, game.width, 50, 'ground');
}
```